# Elegant way of handling different objects in gameloop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am a semi-newbie programming and I am working on a game using python and pygame.
The basic idea is that the player walks around on a big tilemap and does stuff.
So there will be all sorts of objects doing stuff. NPCs moving, grass that grows, bushes that grow, animals that eat grass etc.

I have written a mock version of the game as an example.

```
import pygame

class Plant():

    def __init__(self,name,location,size,edible):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.size = size
        self.edible = edible

class Person():

    def __init__(self,location,name):
        self.location = location
        self.name = name

class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.mainScreen = pygame.display.set_mode(200,200)
        self.objects = []
        self.running = False # start stopped

    def launch(self):
        self.running=True
        self.running_loop()

    def running_loop(self):
        while self.running:
            self.mainScreen.fill((255,255,255))
            # main game loop

            for object in self.objects:

                if type(object) == Person:
                    #do code related to persons
                    pass
                elif type(object) == Plant:
                    # do code related to persons
                    pass

            for object in self.objects:
                pygame.draw(self.mainScreen,object)


           # event handling
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()


#create game instance
game = Game()

#create things in the game
person1 = Person((0,0),"Player")
plant1 = Plant("Bush",(1,1),2,False)
plant2 = Plant("Strawberries",(2,3),1,True)
game.objects.append(person1)
game.objects.append(plant1)
game.objects.append(plant2)


game.launch()
```

So my question is about this part:

```
def running_loop(self):
            while self.running:

                # main game loop

                for object in self.objects:

                    if type(object) == Person:
                        #do code related to persons
                        pass
                    elif type(object) == Plant:
                        # do code related to persons
                        pass

                for object in self.objects:
                    pygame.draw(self.mainScreen,object)
```

There will be a lot of different object in the list that holds all the objects in game. But not all have the same methods, hence the if type(object). I keep thinking there is a more elegant way of doing this. Can I do polymorphism and just write an update method that calls others methods in each instance? The problem with that solution is that I may also need to import classes like pygame's `Rect`. Since this is one of those project that can become very chaotic im trying to do it right from the start.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Sorry. It is my first post so I do not know the format so well.

Answer (score 1):

In pygame it's usually recommended to inherit from [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and put the instances into [sprite groups](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). The `Sprite` class has an `update` method which is supposed to be overridden with the relevant logic for the specific sprite object. You can update all sprites in a sprite group by calling its `update` method which in subsequence calls the `update` methods of all contained sprites, and you can also draw the sprites with `sprite_group.draw(display_surface)`.

There are also ordered and [layered groups](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) if the sprites should appear in a predetermined order.

Here's an [introduction to sprites and groups](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites#section_13) and here's one of my pygame templates:

```
import pygame as pg


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, key_left, key_right, key_up, key_down):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(self.rect.topleft)
        self.speed = 5
        self.key_left = key_left
        self.key_right = key_right
        self.key_up = key_up
        self.key_down = key_down

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == self.key_left:
                self.vel.x = -self.speed
            elif event.key == self.key_right:
                self.vel.x = self.speed
            elif event.key == self.key_up:
                self.vel.y = -self.speed
            elif event.key == self.key_down:
                self.vel.y = self.speed
        elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == self.key_left and self.vel.x < 0:
                self.vel.x = 0
            elif event.key == self.key_right and self.vel.x > 0:
                self.vel.x = 0
            elif event.key == self.key_up and self.vel.y < 0:
                self.vel.y = 0
            elif event.key == self.key_down and self.vel.y > 0:
                self.vel.y = 0


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.fps = 60
        self.done = False
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.player1 = Player((100, 100), pg.K_a, pg.K_d, pg.K_w, pg.K_s)
        self.player2 = Player((200, 200), pg.K_j, pg.K_l, pg.K_i, pg.K_k)
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group(self.player1, self.player2)
        self.background_color = pg.Color('gray12')

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(self.fps) / 1000
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic()
            self.draw()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            for sprite in self.all_sprites:
                sprite.handle_event(event)

    def run_logic(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.background_color)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game().run()
    pg.quit()
```